# Send parent's object and update in childprocess, return to parent process

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, parent-child

I'm trying to parallelize a parts of codes in a program.

There are huge dictionary which contains keys and object.

Object's attribute will be update between child-process.

So I need to pass this dictionary into child-process and update, then return an updated dictionary to parent process for executing.

Here is some sample codes.

```
class ObjectA():

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.list_a = []
        self.list_b = []

class ObjectB():

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.list_a = []
        self.list_b = []

... other objects
```

The program like

```
aa = ObjectA()
aa.name = "object_1"
aa.list_a = [1, 3, 5]
aa.list_b = [2, 4, 6]
bb = ObjectA()
bb.name = "object_2"
bb.list_a = ..
...
cc = ObjectB()
cc.name = "object_3"
...
dd = objectB()
dd.name = "object_4"
...
collection = {}
collection["ObjectA Collection"] = {"object_1": aa, "object_2": bb, ...}
collection["ObjectB Collection] = {"object_3": cc, "object_4": dd, ...}
...
...
p_list = [] # This list include another object definition ObjectC.

do_something(collection) # which_will update collections objects's attribute with list_a or list_b

**Below is the original codes**

for p in p_list:

   col_a = collection["ObjectA Collection"]
   col_b = collection["ObjectB Collection"]

   col_a.update_object_value(p) # update method defined in ObjectA
   col_b.update_object_value(p)
```

I try to split p_list and parallelization

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool
for p in p_list:
    pool.apply_async(update_object_value_method_parallel, argus=(p,))

pool.close()
pool.join()

...
...
leave parallelize
after that, will need dictionary of collection's value which updated by child-process
```

I want to know how to pass this huge dictionary and update between sub-process, I know the `multiprocessing.Manager()`, but I cannot assign class objects into `manager.dict()`, am I right?

How can I hold this dictionary and objects?

Comment: Could it be an option to store the huge dictionary on disk with the dbm or shelve module?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think this will be access to db frequently, because will need to iterate the dictionary in each process. then I have to retrieve dict from db and save back in each process. Is this a good idea?

Comment: My idea was that each thread directly writes to disk, and in the end the parent reads from disk.

Comment: Sounds an option. I'll try, thanks! I have another idea, what if I return each  sub-process's dictionary as list and update parent's dictionary? (edit: But it seems will cost another update time, iterate list and dict to update value)